# Apache 2.2 and virtual hosts in sites-enabled are ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I upgraded from apache 2.0 to apache 2.2, and now all my virtual hosts are ignored.
I'm running a debian server, and I completely upgraded to the new apache2 config file.

in sites-enabled i have all my links to sites-available, which worked perfectly fine before!

When I start the server I get:

```
Reloading web server config: apache2[Sat Oct 17 16:34:22 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

One of the sites-enabled files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /document/root
    ErrorLog /document/root/error_log
    CustomLog /document/root/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem:

Some of my sites-enabled/* files had only:

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

Without the port number... This caused all the other sites to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You should have added the

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Directive above the virtualhost where you declared it - this would have allowed all your configs to work as expected.

The documentation is reasonably clear for this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html